# No SLF4J providers were found warning with fscrawler 2.10

Tags: log4j, fscrawler

I have upgraded fscrawler from 2.9 to 2.10.  I tried the same command towards indexing that I used in the older version:

```
/usr/bin/fscrawler --config_dir /home/user1/conf test_index --restart --loop 1
```

I see the following warning about SLF4J:

```
SLF4J: No SLF4J providers were found.
SLF4J: Defaulting to no-operation (NOP) logger implementation
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#noProviders for further details.
SLF4J: Class path contains SLF4J bindings targeting slf4j-api versions 1.7.x or earlier.
SLF4J: Ignoring binding found at [jar:file:/usr/local/src/fscrawler-distribution-2.10-SNAPSHOT/lib/log4j-slf4j-impl-2.20.0.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See https://www.slf4j.org/codes.html#ignoredBindings for an explanation.
```

I am using Log4j for logging purposes instead of using any Java logging library. How to get rid of the above warning related to SLF4J?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Exception with Slf4j with log4j2 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70660379/exception-with-slf4j-with-log4j2-implementation)

Answer (score 0):

Did you download the latest build or an old one?

Make sure you download the latest build.
That should be fixed.

Comment: I have downloaded version: fscrawler-distribution-2.10-20230501.083424-195.zip

Comment: Does latest build mean v2.9, the released version or the latest available version 2.10-x?

Comment: Weird as this one is normally good to use. I need to check it manually. Could you open an issue in the project with the downloaded version as you wrote above?